# How do I debug a Xamarin app + webapi + SQL Server set-up?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I'm brand new to Xamarin.Forms and Visual Studio (2017 on PC). I'm working with code another (experienced) dev wrote in C# and .NET.

I have a Xamarin app. The app asks me to input data. Then, it saves that data to a SQL Server database via a Web API. Next, later, the app gets that data back from the database to do something.

I can build and publish all projects and the app runs on Android simulator. However, it looks like the data I input is either:

1. Not sent to the DB
2. Not used by the DB

I can tell because when I get the data back from the database, the "something" is wrong.

So here's my question: how do I debug that set-up? I'm familiar with debugging my Xamarin app inside VS 2017, but I don't know how to debug the Web API, or how to look inside the database to see if the data I input are recorded correctly.

At this point, I'm not sure where the bug is, or how to find it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xamarin application:**

As you already mentioned, you can debug your Xamarin app in Visual Studio just like you would any other .Net projects.

**Web API:**

Similarly, you can also debug your Web API project in Visual Studio.

1. Run the Web API project locally.
2. Note the address from the address bar and use that in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or other similar tools to send/receive the API requests/response.

**SQL Server Database:**

You cannot technically 'debug' a database, but you can verify the CRUD operations using SQL Server Management Studio (or [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)) provided you have the necessary access/credentials.

*To find where the error is, I would suggest:*

1. Start from your Xamarin application and verify if the app is sending the JSON as expected;
2. Then send the same JSON from postman to your Web API and verify if it is accepting/processing the JSON as expected;
3. And finally, check your database tables in SSMS if the data is stored as expected.

Refer the following links:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-with-fiddler-and-postman/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thanks for your help. Another (very) newbie question about your point "Run the Web API project locally." To do that, I would run it in VS 2017 using IIS?

Comment: Yes. Simply click on the play button, and it will open up your default browser and then you can debug (hit the break-points) using Postman/Fiddler.

Comment: OK. I get the following errors: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Comment: Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or [...]

Comment: From these options, "run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true" makes the most sense. How would I "run" that? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Open IIS manager (run command: inetmgr) - click on your site (project) and go to 'Directory Browsing' and click enable in the right-hand side panel. By doing this, you have enabled the directory browsing (i.e. listing the contents) for the project.

Comment: Now, the default document part - just add `index.html` in your project.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I've made progress and edited my question. Would you be so kind as to help again?

Comment: You are welcome! Not to be a stickler, but could you please change it back (to the original one) and ask the update as a separate question? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly. Here's the separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787073/web-api-wont-pass-value-to-sql-database

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can debug a web API using Visual Studio almost the same way you debug a Xamarin app. Here's a nice tutorial for that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug